# How many Python applications can I run at the same time per interpreter?

Tags: python

How many Python applications can I run at the same time per interpreter?

Is it just one?

Or could the Python interpreter run more than one at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run only one Python application per interpreter, and you can only run one interpreter per process. If you want to run multiple applications then you will need to run multiple processes.

Answer (score 0):

You can run multiple instances.

Maximum number of instances is only limited by system resources.

Comment: multiple instances of Python interpreter?? So, only one python app per instance of Python interpreter?? Or multiple python apps per one instance of python interpreter??

Comment: There will be one instance (process) per application. You can invoke as many instances you want.